# Where to find Ubuntu downloads for installing on a laptop with a formatted hard disk?

Tags: boot, system-installation, laptop, downloads, iso

My Sony Vaio HDD has been formatted and I want Ubuntu on it--can it be done? And how--I can't even seem to find Linux for laptop OS downloads.

Answer (score 1):

When your Sony Vaio is ready first:

1) Open a browser to: www.ubuntu.com > Click Download > and get the latest DVD version (14.10)

2) Burn the DVD to a disk. (Or use UNETBootIn to burn it to USB Memstick).

3) Turn on the VAIO and as soon as the VAIO screen comes on press F12 (or Delete, or F2 >> the one that allows you to select Boot device

4) Select the DVD Drive (or USB if you used memstick)

5) The Ubuntu dvd will load to a default ubuntu desktop. ON the desktop a shortcut to the installer is there. Double click this and use the Wizard to install Ubuntu from the DVD to your hdd drive as you like.

Enjoy!

Comment: Ubuntu no longer differentiates between laptop and desktop versions of the OS. if you download a version compatible to your architecture, x86 for example, you can install it the same on your laptop or desktop.